# Show a relationship involving proportions

Tags: fractions, percentages, word-problem, ratio

> A ten year comparison between the United States and the Soviet Union
>   in terms of crop yields per acre revealed that when only planted
>   acreage is compared, Soviet yields were equal to 68 percent of United
>   States yields. When total agricultural acreage (planted acreage plus
>   fallow acreage) is compared, however, Soviet yield was 114 percent of
>   US yield. From the information above, show that a higher percentage of
>   total agricultural acreage was fallow in United States than in the
>   Soviet Union.

I keep falsely calculating a result in my process of solving the problem such that the United States has more fallow land than the Soviet Union, but I know this is wrong conclusion by proof by contradiction.

Comment: USP for US planted and SUP for Soviet Union planted. The same for USF and SUF. We know that SUP/USP= $0.68$.

Comment: And we know that (SUF+SUP)/(USF+USP)= $1.14$.

Comment: Now we have two eqs in forur unknown. But we are asked to show that "a higher percentage of total agricultural acreage was fallow in United States than in the Soviet Union." This means to compare : SUF/(SUP+SUF) to the corresponding for US. Thus, we may assume that the corersponding percentage for US is $1$ and compute the Soviet Union percentage.

Comment: why aren't you thinking in terms of crops yields per acre, as in density? If US made $100$ per acre planted then soviet had $68$ per acre planted. There's two units going on here, area and points. points $\neq$ area.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://gre.magoosh.com/forum/526-a-ten-year-comparison-between-the-united-states).

Comment: This was on the GRE?

Comment: don't know that.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, that explanation by Magoosh is garbadge because it isn't written in LaTex. That's really sloppy answer, not your fault but Magoosh's fault.

Comment: We have ourselves a simultaneous equation. Let USF be 'a', SUF be 'b', SUP be 'x', and SUP be 'y'.

x/y=0.64 and (a+x)/(b+y)=1.14


The wording of the questions suggests that it may want us to show this:

a/(x+a+y+b) > b/(x+a+y+b)

or this:

a/(x+a)>b(y+b)

It's likely the latter.